# LaTeX Expert in the World

Tags: rules

Who knows LaTeX the best in the whole world? I'm just a newbie to the wonderful world of LaTeX and I'm wondering who's the go-to-guy (or girl) for help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). The best place to ask for help is not an individual person, but this site. I'd recommend you first make an attempt at using LaTeX and then when you run into a specific problem, feel free to post a question here.  Best way to do that is to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages.

Comment: Just for the record: I voted to close as "not a good fit for our format", which resulted in an automatic downvote. (Hence this is another case of http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2402/wrong-close-reason-shown)

Comment: Whoever the world's top "LaTeX expert" might be, they certainly don't have time to answer your questions. The go-to place for help is here, or other latex forums. comp.text.tex is where the real TeX and LaTeX experts hang out. Some of them are here on this site as well.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the place to go. There's not one single guy, the subject is too large for that. It's a matter of swarm intelligence :-)

Comment: Oh Stephan :) Okay so who's the queen of this swarm of bees?

Comment: Just look at the reputation for a first impression :)

Comment: @Connor: [egreg](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) is [our queen bee](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all) `:)`. But actually, we have different queen bees for different kinds of topics: If you go to one of our [tags](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tags), you can check out the _top users_ in the respective topic. Or you could go through the [tag badges](http://tex.stackexchange.com/badges?tab=tags) (especially the silver and gold ones) to see particularly prolific users in a certain area of TeX expertise.